# Disable specific git commands in a particular repository?

Tags: git

Three times recently, I've done really stupid things while using `git`.  Twice I've run `git reset --hard` on my home-directory repository.  The first time I fat-fingered a reverse-history search in my shell (didn't mean to run it at all), and the second time I was in the wrong terminal window (meant to reset a different repo).  The other mistake was running `git push --mirror ssh://remote-machine/` from the wrong repository.

`git help config` informs me that "To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing git commands are ignored.", so my .git/config aliases

```
[alias]
reset = "!echo no"
push = "!echo wrong repo"
```

are ignored.  Is there a way to do this simply?  I'll likely write a wrapper script of some sort and `alias git=wrapped-git` in my shell, but I was hoping there'd be a simpler way to do it.

*Update*: using the following, based on [grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/276079/disable-specific-git-commands-in-a-particular-repository/276159#276159), but taking advantage of git's built-in configuration system.  This avoids grep'ing an ad-hoc file, and it allows for "cascading" (~/.gitconfig disables 'reset' globally, but per-repo .git/config enables it).  In my .zshrc:

```
git () {
    local disabled=$(command git config --bool disabled.$1 2>/dev/null)
    if ${disabled:-false} ; then
        echo "The $1 command is intentionally disabled" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    command git "$@"
}
```

Comment: facepalm for forgetting gitconfig. =<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not *exactly* a wrapper script – you can create a shell function:

```
git() {
    local gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)
    if [[ $gitdir && -f $gitdir/disabled-commands ]]; then
        # "disabled-commands" should contain "push", "reset", etc
        if grep -Fwqse "$1" "$gitdir/disabled-commands"; then
            echo "You have disabled this command." >&2
            return 1
        else
            command git "$@"
        fi
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

There isn't a simpler way than that.

**Edit:** Added `-e` to grep: without it, grep interfered with calls like `git --version`, which became `grep -Fwqs --version`, and also with tab completion features.

Comment: Accepting, since the answer is that there's no simpler way, and I like using a function vs. a wrapper + alias.  See updated question for what I actually used.